# Mat-option appears at the bottom of the page instead of appearing under mat-select

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to create a drop-down menu, everything works, but my "mat-option" appears at the end of the page, and I have no ideas why. Please explain me what I am doing wrong?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.selectedValue" name="food">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
              {{food.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
    
        </mat-form-field>
```

My css:

```
mat-form-field {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.125;
  font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}



mat-select {
  display: inline-table;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

mat-option {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 92%;
}
```

What i have:
[image]

I expect smth like that:[image][image]

Comment: position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
Remove these from css and it should be fine. But if you expect to get the result shown in the pictures, you should remove the whole css part, and include the material css into your style.css file.

Comment: @DocziSlizard, Thanks! I add import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; to my style.css and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DocziSlizard, Thanks! I add import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; to my style.css and it solved my problem!

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```